# JS map element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i got a array and a map who compare each other. But i got a problem how to check if the array got the element (or key) which is in the map. When the key is not in the array, he should do nothing. the array should decide "okay.. i dont got that element. so i remove the key in the map which is not in use anymore"

here is my source code

```js
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                
  // check if map got array element
  if (!self.map.has(array[i])) {
  self.map.set(array[i]);
   }

  // right here i need your help
  if (array.) {}
}
```

Comment: And/or `find`? And/or `findIndex`? (As I take it `map` is a `Map`, and so you're using ES2015/ES6.)

Comment: @JuleVerne : Did my answer help you? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this perhaps. Find all the keys which are not present in the array. Then iterate over the keys and delete them. Does this work for you?

```
 var keysNotPresentInArray=  Array.from(map.keys()).filter(function(i,index){

        return myArray.indexOf(i)<0;

  });

keysNotPresentInArray.forEach(function(i,index){

     map.delete(i);
  })
```

Comment: i like your idea but the map dont have a filter function(?!) that is what netbeans said... "TypeError: self.myMap.keys(...).filter is not a function"

Comment: You r right. Just changed the answer.can you check now?